# The relationship between dependent decision variables in a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Given objective function f(x1,x2,x3) in a optimization problem, and don't know if all these variables are independent or not. How to know if dx2/dx3 is greater/less than/equal to zero. I could

Comment: This appears to have been posted in incomplete form. Please add an example. As for what is in the post thus far, maybe use implicit differentiation at the extremal point to evaluate such derivatives.

Comment: Did you mean to post this on [math.se]? This is the site for the computing software package Mathematica.